# How can I remove short bursts noises in a recording?

Tags: audio-recording, audacity

I try to clean a recording of a lecture that has noises of turning of pages or a chair squeaking. I want to get rid of (completely silence) any sound shorter than 100ms exceeding a general silence of -48dB. Can I do this. preferably in audacity? I've tried click removal butdidn't get satisfactory results with[image] any parameters.

I've marked below what I try to remove.

[!example[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYc0D.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYc0D.jpg)

Comment: There is specialized software for this sort of task, for example [iZotope RX](https://www.izotope.com/en/products/repair-and-edit/rx/post.html). It features removal of clicks, which seems to be what you're looking for, but also a lot of other things. The software I mentioned has a 10-day trial mode in which, if I'm reading it correctly, you have access to all features.

Answer (score -1):

Do you want to automate it? Perhaps with a noise profile or just select it manually and use a silence command. I like the cool edit pro software now called adobe audition.

You can also look at the spectograph and draw an delete unwanted frequencies within a timeframe.

Perhaps Imagination Studio would be a good investment as an alternative software package?

For osalt preferrers Ubuntu Studio comes with decent software like ardour audacity and vokoscreen and now cheese. It seem to be better suited for webcasting.

I like the functional pseudocode algorithm idea you have here:

> I want to get rid of (completely silence) any sound shorter than 100ms exceeding a general silence of -48dB

I want to learn that too. I think you need to know how the audio is encoded before you can start dividing. Segments into 101ms does your software auto select the beat with arrow keys to start of next note? Perhaps Autokey or Autohotkey can help but you would need a way to check the sound length.  Or manually sit there and press next like f3 finds

Comment: I want to automate it - deleting every short noise.

Comment: You didnt mention what software. You can try limiting the frequencys with the EQ Equalizer function. Sometimes this is also called High Pass and Low Pass filters. That means you cut signals you dont need like high pitched fuzz/hiss or tones so low the speaker you use can reproduce the sound. For the speakers they call that EQ a crossover it sends low to subwoofer and hi to tweeters.

Comment: In Adobe Audio I could select a "NOISE PROFILE" google it. Other wise try to manually select drag and silence.